WebRequest Header Modification on other extensions
I am currently trying to write a compatibility extension for raindrop.io. Some hosts I am working with a lot require some additional fields added to the header, otherwise they reject the request. Because of this, the image preview of raindrop.io does not work properly.
Long story short, I got this working via WebRequestBlocking already for when raindrop.io is opened in the main frame. It's a rather standard issue after all.
Here's the relevant code (Yes, I'm not filtering the url at all right now... I'm still experimenting)
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Referer Modifier",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "referer-modifier@extension.com"
        }
    }
}


browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        const headers = details.requestHeaders;
        /* DO HEADER MODIFICATION
        It works in main frame. Not releveant for the question, so I cut it out.
        */
        return {requestHeaders: headers};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);

Again, it's basically the absolut basic example straight from documentation. It works in the main frame.
My question is... is there some way I can set this up, so it can also intercept requests made by the other extension, so that the sidebar and such work too? I tried searching through the documentation, but I'm not really deep into extension development, so I have no idea what terms I should even be looking for.

No, it's impossible, intentionally so.

Ok, thank you. Not a big surprise to be honest.
I still need to solve the underlying issue somehow... Does anyone have some suggestions what some alternative options would be in this case?

It might be possible using chrome.debugger API and definitely possible via chrome.devtools API which works while you inspect another extension's page.

Either of those does not really sound like something suitable for a permanent setup. Hmm...
Is there a way that I can register an extension as a "patch" of another extension of sorts?
... or maybe I should simply pack my own version of the raindrop.io extension instead.

See How to modify an extension from the Chrome Web Store?

Thank you for the pointers. This should get me back on track.
